# Text logo to Image logo - Joomla 1.5 template

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-template

Wonder if any of the good folks can assist..

I have installed a basic theme Joomla 1.5 template but looking to change the text writing of the site name to our image logo.

Here is the code in the source at the moment.

```
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl = JURI::base();?>"><?php echo $mainframe->getCfg('sitename');?></a></div>
```

Tried img src tag etc but no success...

What will be the right way of doing this create a custom html module and position there? Or is there an alternate php way one is missing?

Thanks for your assistance in advance.

Kof

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the site name go to joomla configuration and change it there

or you can modify the configuration.php file or

simply change the html code :

```
<div id="logo"><a href="<?php echo $baseurl = JURI::base();?>"><?php echo JText::_('MY_NEW_SITE_NAME');?></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your site is set up to display the site name in that div, that is controlled in the Global Configuration. If the text displays and you want to change it, look in Site > Global Configuration > Site > Site Settings > Site Name.

If the text name is not displaying, it is because the logo is being placed in to the div as a background image. You should look in your template CSS to see what you have defined for #logo. You can also use Chrome/Firefox, right click on the current logo and select inspect element. that should also show you the CSS for the element and tell you where the image is coming from.

Comment: Thanks for your input Brent, much appreciated and now becoming clearer.